# How can I count the number of days (Monday, Tues, etc) in a year?

Tags: date-and-time, procedural-programming

I am new to Mathematica and for fun am trying some of the challenges. The one I am working on now is:

```
Write a function MostOccurringWeekday that takes an integer representing a year as input and returns a list of the most-occurring weekdays throughout that year.
```

I'm not sure where to start? I assume I'll have to do a loop from 1/1/[YEAR] to 12/31/[YEAR] and count each weekday.

This is my attempt at getting a date:

```
year = 1998
Interpreter["Date"][StringForm["1/1/``", year]]
```

But this results in an error.

If anyone could give some pointers, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Lookup [`DayCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DayCount)

Comment: *I assume I'll have to do a loop from ....* Whoaaa, slow down there. In a 365-day year there are 53 occurrences of the day on which the year starts, 52 occurrences of each of the other days. Try something like `DateString[{2018}, "DayName"]` and work the rest out.